# Getting callback result

Tags: c#, callback, asynccallback

I am writing a C# asynchronously library with delegate and callback to prevent blocking. I am also using a third-party library which is using the same callback methodology.

How can I get the status from a the thrid party listener into my callback?

Code:

```
public class myController
{
    private ThirdPartyController thirdPartyController ;
    public delegate void ConnectedDelegate(string status);

    public myController()
    {
        thirdPartyController = ThirdPartyController .getInstance(new MyControllerListener());
    }

    public void Connect(ConnectedDelegate callback)
    {
        3PartyController.start();
        callback(<<Connectedstatus>>); // <= How to get status from onConnected? 
    }
}

public class MyControllerListener: ThirdPartyControllerListener
{
    public void onConnected(ConnnectedStatus status)
    {
        // Want status from here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not using `async/await` and `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`?

Comment: Also, declaring your own delegate type is not usually a good idea unless you have a very complex signature with lots of nested generics. For something that takes a `string` and returns `void`, just use `System.Action<string>`

Comment: Third party library is using callback... but my library can be async/await... but some of my company client is not using the latest .net library...

Comment: That's a shame. They should upgrade. It has been out for like 7 years

Comment: use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to communicate between your callback delegate invoked by the library, and your own code, which then can use `await` with the `Task` from the `TaskCompletionSource<T>` object. See marked duplicate for examples.

Comment: @PeterDuniho if you see the comments, he can't use `async/await` because of legacy clients.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: if you see the comments, you'll see it written that _"my library can be async/await"_

Comment: Some of client is using legacy application written "century" ago...

Comment: @PeterDuniho _"but my library can be async/await... but some of my company client is not using the latest .net library..."_

Comment: @PeterDuniho third party library is using callback.

Comment: @Alvin but are _you_ able to use `async/await` and target .NET>=4.5?

Comment: @AluanHaddad you can give answer of using async/await, but some of the target is < 4.5....

Comment: @Alvin what I am asking is simply: Can the code you need to write leverage `async/await` when it is _not_ interacting with the third party library in question?

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes.

Comment: Then this is indeed a duplicate